# Magento SSL Checkout - not found

Tags: php, magento, ssl

I have a valid SSL certificate installed on a managed server. I enable ssl by going system->configuration->web and setting "Secure"-> Base Url: https://www.mydomain.com and changing "Use Secure URLs in Frontend": Yes.

When I try and checkout it redirects to https://www.mydomain.com/checkout/onepage/. This page cannot be found...

The thing is there is a secure directory on the server (public_ssl) and non secure (public html), should the public_ssl directory be empty? How is magento suppose to asccess files that aren't there?

I have tried copying over the index.php, .htaccess, skin, js & media folders/files to public_ssl, which works but then the media isn't updated when I upload a product image etc...

(I edited the index.php "MAGENTO_ROOT" global to find the appropriate files...)

Am I Missing something?

Comment: It's just a setting in your Apache virtualhost. Try changing `AllowOverride None` to `AllowOverride All`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution is to contact you hosting provider. They may be able to modify the way their ssl is configured (https://serverfault.com/questions/429634/restrict-apache-to-only-allow-access-using-ssl-for-some-directories) or use a symlink so that the content will be shared between public_ssl and your public html folder.

Also, for better site performance it's always best to host you magento website on a service provider who specializes in magento hosting.